# Xamarin.Forms: PCL -> .Net Standard upgrade

Tags: xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I'm nearly done with my app. I'm using Xamarin.Forms (PCL project for the shared code). Is there any benefit of switching PCL into .Net Strandard? I have read some articles, but still not 100% sure whether are there any benefits of upgrading, e.g. security, performance or is't more like richer API mainly? Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct improvement in security or performance, but in time .NET Standard will replace PCLs. The PCL is not as cross-platform as Standard, so to make it truly cross-platform the switch to Standard is the smart thing to do.

Also, a lot of NuGet packages are already switching to support Standard, and you will not receive any upgrades for that code in your PCL library. So coming back to the security and performance part; if a bug is found in a NuGet package, you will not receive the update containing a fix because you're still on the 'older' PCL technology. This is a bit of a stretch, but if you want to be future-proof, the switch to .NET Standard is mandatory.

Right now we're in a bit of a pickle. You cannot reference a Standard from a PCL and vice versa (not 100% sure on all scenario's but I think you can't). So, right now you have to carefully check if all NuGets you are using, have a .NET Standard version already. If not, you're stuck on a PCL if you can't do it without the NuGet. The creator of the NuGet could supply a PCL and .NET Standard version in one NuGet, so then you can transition from one to the other. But see if that is true for all plugins you are using.

There is actually a good post on this by Adam Pedley [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: Are there any limitations or exceptions that will occur when upgrading from PCL to .NET Standard?

Comment: What about if a "nuget package" does not yet support .Net Standard? does that mean you will not be able to use that package?

Comment: Thanks @Gerald. This blog post also explains about [upgrading or creating Xamarin.Forms Apps with .NET Standard](https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/).

Comment: Thanks! And please accept it as one if it helped @Pablo

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can refer a PCL from .netstandard and vice versa, but it depends on netstandard version and PCL profile. Refer to [this table](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md#mapping-pcl-profiles-to-net-standard) to find out what is possible in your case.

To move from PCL to netstandard:

1. Replace *.csproj content with this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable45-net45+win81+wpa8</PackageTargetFallback>
    <Copyright>Copyright ©  2018</Copyright>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2. You can add PackageTargetFallback tag if you want add references to PCL libraries. Also you can edit the value you need. In the example above I use "portable45-net45+win81+wpa8" to add PCL(Profile111) in the netstandard1.1 library.

3. Use the netstandard version [you need](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md#mapping-pcl-profiles-to-net-standard). Copy info from "AssemblyInfo.cs" to the project settings (Properties->Package) and remove it as you don't need it anymore.

4. Manually install back nuget packages from "packages.config" file and scan old *.csproj file for references to you projects. Add them as well. Then you can remove "packages.config" file as well.

I tried it on VS2017 15.7.5. I found that it's better to use netstandard1.1 and profile111 if you develop for Xamarin.Forms (Android + iOS). In this case, you can still use old .NETPortable nuget packages (even though they don't support netstandard yet).